# Did they shoot a different ending?

Tags: star-wars, alternate-version, rogue-one

In the **[Rogue One - Celebration Reel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HUb_zpdyDpU)** and the **[Rogue One - Teaser Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wji-BZ0oCwg)** we saw footage that didn't appear in the theatrical cut, which isn't unusual.

However, these shots of Jyn, Cassian and Krennic on the beach seem to suggest a different third act.

[image: Rogue One]
  [image: Rogue One]
  [image: Rogue One]

In the movie Jyn goes from the data vault straight to the top of the tower to transmit the plans. Cassian was lying at the bottom of the vault, Krennic was following Jyn.

Looking at the footage above makes me wonder if the [reported reshoots](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Why-Star-Wars-Rogue-One-Reshoots-Might-Bad-Everyone-Pretending-135027.html) changed the ending. Did Jyn and Cassian escape with the physical copy of the plans? Or are those scenes just part of an extended escape scene that got cut out completely.

**My Question:**

- Did the reshoots change the ending (Jyn and Cassian escaping with a physical copy of the plans) or was the third act just cut short?

Comment: @JakeGould - Please don't reformat my question. That's the way I like to do it: I explain first, then I ask the question, not the other way around.

Answer (score 7):

## Yes, kind of.

- Yes, they planned (or at least wanted) to have Jyn and Cassian to live, (and presumably to escape with the physical copy), [as per Gareth Edwards interiew](http://heroichollywood.com/spoilers-gareth-edwards-talks-rogue-one-ending/), but the Story Group went all homicidal on them and said "nobody survives".

  > For ever single character to die in all their movies. I think there was an early version – the very first version they didn’t [die] in the screenplay. And it was just assumed by us that we couldn’t do that and they’re not gonna let us do that. So we’re trying to figure out how this ends where that doesn’t happen. And then everyone read that, and there was just this feeling of like, “They gotta die right?” And everyone was like, “Yeah, can we?” And we thought we weren’t gonna be allowed to, but Kathy [Kennedy] and everyone at Disney were like, “Yeah, makes sense.” I guess they have to because they’re not in A New Hope. And so from that point on, we had the license and I kept waiting for someone to go, “You know what, can you just film an extra scene where we see Jyn and Cassian, they’re okay, and they’re on another planet and la la la…” And [that] never ever came, and no one gave us that note so we got to do it.

Comment: I could be wrong, but his sounds like the changes were made early on, during the script development, not later, during the reshoots. - It has been pointed out to me that Jyn and Cassian are running towards a radio tower (one can see the tower in the second picture above; a few frames later, when the camera pans up, one can see a big dish on top), which would mean they aren't actually trying to escape in this scene, they are still trying to transmit the plans.

Comment: @Oliver_C  - I think one version i saw mentioned was them escaping from top of tower